# SQL Count Types and return all items under those counts

Tags: sql-server

I am using the following SQL Query to get the count of several item types under 20. What I am trying to do is extract all the rows that fall into the category. There are other types which have counts over 20 but I don't particularly care about those.

```
 SELECT ITEM_TYPE, COUNT(ITEM_NUMBER) As "COUNT"
     FROM TOTAL_COLLECTION 
     group by ITEM_TYPE
     HAVING Count(ITEM_TYPE) < 20;
```

RESULT:

```
C15     9
C1SRT   1
CA7     7
D4S5M   10
D4S7M   4
D5S7E   2
```

For example: I have 9 counts that fall into C15.

```
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(ITEM_TYPE)) AS ITEM_TYPE, ITEM_STATUS, ITEM_NUMBER
FROM TOTAL_COLLECTION 
WHERE ITEM_TYPE in ('c15')

C15 2   000540176
C15 2   000384552
C15 2   000452976
C15 2   000372632
C15 2   000573561
C15 2   000592110
C15 2   000465054
C15 2   000394784
C15 2   000400305
```

I am trying to combine the results of the first query, to give me a complete list of all those types. All the fields are found in one table.

I tried to find an answer for this question, but I wasn't able to locate one. If I somehow missed this, I apologize for the duplicate. I am still pretty new to SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(ITEM_TYPE)) AS ITEM_TYPE, ITEM_STATUS, ITEM_NUMBER
FROM TOTAL_COLLECTION 
WHERE ITEM_TYPE in (
    SELECT ITEM_TYPE
    FROM TOTAL_COLLECTION 
    group by ITEM_TYPE
    HAVING Count(ITEM_TYPE) < 20
)
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize I could just combine both of my queries into one. This gave me the needed results.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming SQL Server 2008+, you can use the `OVER` clause:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            N = COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY ITEM_TYPE)
    FROM dbo.TOTAL_COLLECTION
)
SELECT  LTRIM(RTRIM(ITEM_TYPE)) AS ITEM_TYPE, 
        ITEM_STATUS, 
        ITEM_NUMBER
FROM CTE 
WHERE N < 20;
```

Comment: This works very well. I like the sophistication of the query. I appreciate your help.